# Javascript Dot Notation = Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax

Dot notation allows for accessing objects with a '.' Cannot figure out why this is happening. I have the following success function, as part of a jQuery $.ajax function.

```
success: function(data){
  console.log('data = ' + data);
  console.log('data.president = ' + data.president);
  console.log('data.adviser = ' + data.adviser);
}
```

This, oddly, results in the following browser log:

```
data = {"president":1,"adviser":1}
data.president = undefined
data.adviser = undefined
```

I must be missing something painfully obvious. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: I would suggest using commas in your `console.log`'s instead of string concatenation. For example, see the difference between `console.log('data = ' + {})` and `console.log('data = ', {})`

Comment: `data` is a string. The point is that the console omits the " at the edges of it, making it resemble to an object, but it is not. It is the JSON serializazion of the object. Try add dataType: 'json' to the ajax request to convert it automatically to js object.

Comment: @Stryner Interesting. Can you elaborate on why commas are preferable? I ran that: concatenation returns `data = [object Object]` and commas return `data =  Object {}`

Comment: Commas are preferable because they preserve the type of the objects being logged. With string concatenations, all objects will be changed to `[object Type]`, which gives you less information. In the console I use (Firebug for Firefox), I'm able to inspect the object that's logged; I'm not sure if that's universal.

Comment: @Stryner very helpful, I appreciate the info. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data would have to be an Object to be accessed by a dot `.`.
It's a string now.
You need to parse it using for example:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Ideally though, the server would set the proper MIME type for the response and jQuery would automatically parse the response as JSON. Or as A. Wolff just pointed out, use `dataType: "json"`

Comment: There is no JSON object, JSON is a notation for object, here javascript one

Comment: Derp. Like I said, painfully obvious. Good call on this, and also a shout-out to A. Wolff & Peter on the dataType/MIME type. That was really what I was missing from the AJAX call. Appreciate the help, folks!

Answer (score 4):

Set `dataType: "json"` as ajax option so jQuery would parse your string `data` to javascript object

Answer (score 0):

You define the **data** elements has **strings**,  attributes of an object need to be declared without quotes, like this:

```
data = {president:1,adviser:1}
```

in that case you got the expected result

```
data.president = 1
data.adviser = 1
```